# Adding Image into Django Admin ImageField and displaying it in html

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

Could anyone give a simple working example how to display in html file images added through ImageField in Django Admin? There are many solutions to specific problems but I could not found one simple tutorial how to do it properly.

Comment: Is `<img src="{{image_field.url}}">` in a template not working? Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, it's not working. I just want to add the image file from the Django Admin and then display it in the html file. I specified the 'upload_to' argument in the admin, but when I call {{image_field.url}} I get a log that this image was not found. I am wondering what else and where do I need to add to make Django display this image in html file.

Comment: Did you get any error when uploading from the admin? Can you access the image when returning to the admin? Also, can you check in the database directly what is in the field?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an extra field in the admin class?

In admins.py:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
from django.contrib.admin import register, ModelAdmin

@register MyModel
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ('image_preview',)

    def image_preview(self, obj):
        image_field = getattr(obj, 'image', '')
        return format_html(u'<img src="{}" />', image_field.url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe I was not specific enough, I meant in html file, not in the Django Admin.

Comment: How about `<img src="{{image_field.url}}">` in a template, is it not working?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but the image remains empty as if the source was not found.

Comment: What does it look like in the rendered HTML? Is the SRC attribute actually empty? If the file is not found, this might be a static file configuration issue. Read more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Comment: It is empty with the question mark in the middle. Ok, I'll read once again tutorial from Django.